# when I give my text box as empty it should not inside my if condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

- I have a dropdown
- when I select test 1 I should display grid 1
- when I slect test 2 it should not display anything.
- when I give my text box as empty it should not inside my if condition but not its going inside my if condition
  $("#mickey").val() != null
- can you tell me how to fix it .
- providing my code below.
  http://jsfiddle.net/oofvt0Lw/

```or-tag-here
  if ($('#combo :selected').text() === "Test 1" && datepicker.value() != null && $("#mickey").val() != null) {
    alert("test 1 selected");
    $("#grid1").show();
  } else {
    alert("test 2 selected");
    $("#grid1").hide();
  }
```

Comment: `val()` will never return `null`. If an input has no value then `val()` returns an empty string, which is not the same as `null`

Comment: JS is truthy/falsy (not strict) so instead of .value() != null, just use .value().trim() as "" == false